# GCM iOS can't convert message object received

Tags: ios, swift2, google-cloud-messaging

I m using GCM for iOS and I receive the message that I push but the message look like this object :

```
[aps: {
    alert =     {
        body = "great match!";
        title = "Portugal vs. Denmark";
    };
}, gcm.message_id: 0:1464264430528872......]
```

Here is the entire function called when I receive a message :

```
 func application( application: UIApplication,
                      didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                                                   fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
        print(userInfo)
        // This works only if the app started the GCM service
        GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        // Handle the received message
        // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
                                                                  userInfo: userInfo)
        handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
```

I don't find how to get the alert body and alert title how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userInfo` is a dictionary of type [NSObject : AnyObject]. To access the values, use subscripting.

The "aps" key contains a dictionary which contains a dictionary, so, for example, you could do:

```
if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String:[String:String]],
        alert = aps["alert"],
        body = alert["body"],
        title = alert["title"] {
    print(title)
    print(body)
}
```